# WifiP2pManager.discoverPeers fails in android 10

Tags: android, android-10.0, wifip2p, peer-discovery

following code sample returns Error code: 0, which is the error code for internal error in android. Is there any workaround which can enable discovering peers in android 10 devices?

```
                wifip2pmanager.discoverPeers(wifip2pmanagerChannel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    status.setText("Peer Discovery Started");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int reason) {

                    status.setText("Error code:" + reason);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Have you declared `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission in your manifest?

Comment: Yes. Both `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` are declared.

Answer (score 8):

Exactly the same happened to me...

`ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` are not enough. The user has to explcitly activate the location services!
(in my case turning on location solved the problem...)

This means: Either you activate location in your settings manually or you make a usability friendly request to the user to activate location services (looks similar to permission request window; see google maps)

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61339719/how-to-ask-user-to-turn-on-location) for example code of the latter. Hope this helps!

Edit: If you search for an anwser that not envolves any Google libs, see the anwser to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53681936/ask-user-to-enable-gps-location-in-android-without-googleapi-or-google-play-serv).

Comment: Hi, I had asked for both permissions and they ARE allowed when I check app info. Yet I still get reason code 1. (my location is on too)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the statement in the list, you also need to dynamically apply for this permission.

Comment: Removing `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` did the trick. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I tried Both with and without Permision Still Getting Error

Comment: You have to turn on `location`  in your settings. Pls see my [anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67545267/5392548)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the issue today when using android 33, solved it by adding `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and `NEARBY_WIFI_DEVICES`. To ask for app permissions: when the activity is onCreate()

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            android.Manifest.permission.NEARBY_WIFI_DEVICES,
    }, 0);
    ...
}
```

To check for granted/denied permissions:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        for(int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++){
            if(grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Permission " + permissions[i] + " granted");
            }else{
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Permission " + permissions[i] + " denied");
            }
        }
    }

}
```