# wifip2pManager.discoverPeers() fails IN ANDROID 10 despite of using runtime permission and in Manifest too

Tags: java, android, wifip2p

I was trying to run the wifidirectdemo app provided on wifip2p page of documentation but on android 10 its not running perfectly.I tried the solution mentioned on [WifiP2pManager.discoverPeers fails in android 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63340713/wifip2pmanager-discoverpeers-fails-in-android-10) ,but nothing helped.All other wifip2p functions are running normally only this is causing issue and returns 0 i.e. ERROR code.
Thanks for any suggestion.

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.deom">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <!-- Google Play filtering -->


    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi.direct" android:required="true"/>

    <application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">


    <activity android:name=".WiFiDirectActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTask">


    <intent-filter>

    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

</intent-filter>

</activity>


        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>



    <!-- Used for transferring files after a successful connection -->


    <service android:name=".FileTransferService" android:enabled="true"/>

</application>

</manifest>
```

WifiDirectActivity.java

```
package com.example.deom;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pConfig;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pDevice;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.ActionListener;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.Channel;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.ChannelListener;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;


/**
 * An activity that uses WiFi Direct APIs to discover and connect with available
 * devices. WiFi Direct APIs are asynchronous and rely on callback mechanism
 * using interfaces to notify the application of operation success or failure.
 * The application should also register a BroadcastReceiver for notification of
 * WiFi state related events.
 */
public class WiFiDirectActivity extends Activity implements ChannelListener, DeviceListFragment.DeviceActionListener {

    public static final String TAG = "wifidirectdemo";

    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1001;

    private WifiP2pManager manager;
    private boolean isWifiP2pEnabled = false;
    private boolean retryChannel = false;

    private final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    private Channel channel;
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = null;

    /**
     * @param isWifiP2pEnabled the isWifiP2pEnabled to set
     */
    public void setIsWifiP2pEnabled(boolean isWifiP2pEnabled) {
        this.isWifiP2pEnabled = isWifiP2pEnabled;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION:
            if  (grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Fine location permission is not granted!");
                finish();
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    private boolean initP2p() {
        // Device capability definition check
        if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_WIFI_DIRECT)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Wi-Fi Direct is not supported by this device.");
            return false;
        }

        // Hardware capability check
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if (wifiManager == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Cannot get Wi-Fi system service.");
            return false;
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            if (!wifiManager.isP2pSupported()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Wi-Fi Direct is not supported by the hardware or Wi-Fi is off.");
                return false;
            }
        }

        manager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
        if (manager == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Cannot get Wi-Fi Direct system service.");
            return false;
        }


        channel = manager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);
        if (channel == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Cannot initialize Wi-Fi Direct.");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // add necessary intent values to be matched.

        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);

        if (!initP2p()) {
            finish();
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M
                    && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    WiFiDirectActivity.PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
            // After this point you wait for callback in
            // onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[]) overridden method
        }
    }

    /** register the BroadcastReceiver with the intent values to be matched */
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        receiver = new WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(manager, channel, this);
        registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    /**
     * Remove all peers and clear all fields. This is called on
     * BroadcastReceiver receiving a state change event.
     */
    public void resetData() {
        DeviceListFragment fragmentList = (DeviceListFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_list);
        DeviceDetailFragment fragmentDetails = (DeviceDetailFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_detail);
        if (fragmentList != null) {
            fragmentList.clearPeers();
        }
        if (fragmentDetails != null) {
            fragmentDetails.resetViews();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_items, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)
     */
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.atn_direct_enable:
                if (manager != null && channel != null) {

                    // Since this is the system wireless settings activity, it's
                    // not going to send us a result. We will be notified by
                    // WiFiDeviceBroadcastReceiver instead.

                    startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "channel or manager is null");
                }

                return true;

            case R.id.atn_direct_discover:
                if (!isWifiP2pEnabled) {
                    Toast.makeText(WiFiDirectActivity.this, R.string.p2p_off_warning,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
                final DeviceListFragment fragment = (DeviceListFragment) getFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_list);
                fragment.onInitiateDiscovery();
                manager.discoverPeers(channel, new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        Toast.makeText(WiFiDirectActivity.this, "Discovery Initiated",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int reasonCode) {
                        Toast.makeText(WiFiDirectActivity.this, "Discovery Failed : " + reasonCode,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void showDetails(WifiP2pDevice device) {
        DeviceDetailFragment fragment = (DeviceDetailFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_detail);
        fragment.showDetails(device);

    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    public void connect(WifiP2pConfig config) {
        manager.connect(channel, config, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                // WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver will notify us. Ignore for now.
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int reason) {
                Toast.makeText(WiFiDirectActivity.this, "Connect failed. Retry.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void disconnect() {
        final DeviceDetailFragment fragment = (DeviceDetailFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_detail);
        fragment.resetViews();
        manager.removeGroup(channel, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int reasonCode) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Disconnect failed. Reason :" + reasonCode);

            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                fragment.getView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onChannelDisconnected() {
        // we will try once more
        if (manager != null && !retryChannel) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Channel lost. Trying again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            resetData();
            retryChannel = true;
            manager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), this);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Severe! Channel is probably lost premanently. Try Disable/Re-Enable P2P.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelDisconnect() {

        /*
         * A cancel abort request by user. Disconnect i.e. removeGroup if
         * already connected. Else, request WifiP2pManager to abort the ongoing
         * request
         */
        if (manager != null) {
            final DeviceListFragment fragment = (DeviceListFragment) getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_list);
            if (fragment.getDevice() == null
                    || fragment.getDevice().status == WifiP2pDevice.CONNECTED) {
                disconnect();
            } else if (fragment.getDevice().status == WifiP2pDevice.AVAILABLE
                    || fragment.getDevice().status == WifiP2pDevice.INVITED) {

                manager.cancelConnect(channel, new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        Toast.makeText(WiFiDirectActivity.this, "Aborting connection",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int reasonCode) {
                        Toast.makeText(WiFiDirectActivity.this,
                                "Connect abort request failed. Reason Code: " + reasonCode,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From android 10, location permission even though if granted at runtime by the user ,the app will not run.We have to either turn on manually the gps(location) from settings bar or open the setting programmatically to turn on gps and then run the app.This time as long as the gps(location) is ON discoverPeers() will run normally with no errors.Though on below devices GPS is not required.

Comment: Still facing Same Issuse